# Is it possible to post questions via email?

Tags: support, asking-questions, email

I don't have internet during the day and I need to post by email. Is it possible?

Comment: @animuson? A duplicate? This isn't even about Stack Exchange sites..

Comment: @MartijnPieters THe user is clearly asking if he can **Post** on the site via email. Why isn't this about stack exchange. Also this duplicate is so unrelated I don't even want to comment.

Comment: @Martijn I interpreted it as he wanted to include his email as part of the question because he wouldn't be able to check it throughout the day.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd: That's not clear to me *from the question posted here*. I see that the OP has posted a similar question on Stack Overflow that does seem to suggest that the OP wants to post to Stack Exchange sites by email, but that information is entirely lacking here.

Comment: @animuson I was thinking that he was asking if he could send an email to SO and the email text would start a new question. It's really unclear, though.

Comment: @animuson: see [is Posible post a topic from my cellphone without internet?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22802655) Same user on Stack Overflow; ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd had it right and the OP wants to post via email.

Comment: @MartijnPieters *to suggest that the OP wants to post by email, but that information is entirely lacking here.*.. what about the title that says it all ? Help I don't have Internet during the day and I need to **post by email. is it posible?**

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd: given the OPs lack of English grammar everywhere else, that title is at best highly ambiguous.

Comment: @iJoe if you don't have internet connection, you also can't send email. So....

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to bother any of you guys. I live in a country where cell phone just got email services. I just can connect to internet at home with a modem "multi tech" (Its my litter dinosaur ) but that's the best we can get. I live in Cuban an Island in the golf of Mexico. I understand OP doesn't allow to Post by email. I'll have to wait every night to Post. Thanx for your support

Answer (score 3):

No. It isn't possible to submit questions or answers via email.